# Invoke-SqlCmd change -QueryTimeout setting to 5 seconds

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

My code works but I'd like the query to timeout faster then the default 15 seconds (I think that's what it is.)
I've tried using -QueryTimeout 5 but it appears to still clock to ~15 seconds before it times out.
Is there a way to set it to 5 seconds, or whatever value I choose?

I'm running my Powershell code through Visual Studio Code:
**Version: 1.76.1 (user setup)
Commit: 5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b
Date: 2023-03-08T16:32:00.131Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.14393
Sandboxed: No**

Comment: The default for a query is 30 seconds.  Do you want to change the query time or the connection time.

Comment: See the `-ConnectionTimeout` and `-QueryTimeout` parameters from `help Invoke-Sqllcmd`.

Comment: I want to change the query time.  So if the query doesn't return a result in, let's say, 8 seconds, move on to the next server in the server list.

Comment: I did look into the -QueryTimeout parameters.  My original question said that.  I will look into the -ConnectionTimeout though.